# problem while using tiff and gif format images with UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uiwebview, gif

I have a web page using css and javascript and also this webpages have tiff and gif images.  When i loaded this webpage locally in ipad it is not working as i can only see white page and not my images.  But when i moved this folder to one of the server and when i tried to load this website remotely.  I got this error: 
      "_CGImagePluginInitGIFmalformed GIF file (1024 x 748)"

But It is working properly.  So i was wondering if there is any problem using the tiff and gif images locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the javascript files which i moved to the copy Bundle Resources from Compile Sources.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there's *really* a error in the GIF?

If you're able to open the GIF in an other application, try to re-save it. It will probably fix the malformation. If it doesn't work try to save it in an other format. (Try OS X's Preview, it's good for these kind of things...)

Comment: no gif is working fine and if i use the gif format in webview it should work fine as per the Apple's documentation.